# In C++, what is the lifetime/scope of a constructor call without a variable name?

Tags: c++, scope, lifetime

During some coding this morning I managed to enter and compile something akin to the following.

```
void a_function(void)
{
    A_Class(std::string);
    ... //Other code continues
}
```

(names have been replaced to protect the identity of those classes involved)

What I had intended to have was a named instance `A_Class an_instance(a_string);` which I know would be in scope until the end of the function.  What is the scope and lifetime of the A_Class created in this function?

---

I expect I could do something clever in the construction phase to make the lifetime almost anything I want.  In this case the constructor makes a function call and a printf while the destructor does similar.  Nothing invokes `new`, `delete`, `malloc` or anything of that sort.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor and destructor and find out!

Comment: This is completely trivial to figure out with a few `std::cout` statements.

Comment: @rozina I would live to do that if the tool chain I was working on had any helpful debug facilities besides printf.  I was hoping for an easier route to the answer than eyeballing the optimised assembly output.

Comment: Then put a printf in the constructor and destructor and another one after the line `A_Class();`.

Comment: @juanchopanza that is exactly what I am going in the space between asking the question and checking for other people's answers.  If there are no good ones in that 30min period I will post my answer.  4 minutes after a question is asked could still be me typing up the Q&A style post.

Comment: OK, well, there's nothing clever you can do. The lifetime of the object is determined by the rules of the language. Also, `A_Class() an_instance;` looks like a typo. You probably meant `A_Class an_instance;`

Comment: @juanchopanza `A_Class() an_instance;` was a typo but `A_Class an_instance();` was what I had meant to type.  I will update the question.

Comment: No, you really don't mean do declare a function :-) (I know, C++ is weird like that...)

Answer (score 3):

Since C++98, a temporary lasts until the end of the full-expression, unless its lifetime is extended by binding to a reference.

The rules were different, as I recall, in ARM (the Annotated Reference Manual by Stroustrup and Ellis) C++.

It's not generally possible to figure out the standard's guarantees by just inspecting examples in a debugger or via trace statements, so the question has merit.

Answer (score 2):

Only names have scope, so that concept is irrelevant here.

You're creating a temporary object.
Like all temporary objects, its lifetime lasts until the end of the *full-expression* where it was created, i.e until the ";" in this case, unless it's bound to a const reference variable.

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
A_Class();
```

creates a temporary object of class `A_Class`. The temporary is destroyed after the evaluation of the full expression which lexicaly contains it -- in this case, the temporary will be destroyed immediately after its construction.

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to answer my own question,

### Second Attempt

Updated test code now reads:

```
#include <iostream>

class Class_A 
{
public:
  Class_A(std::string a_string) 
    : saved_string(a_string)
  {
    std::cout << "Class_A Constructed:" << saved_string << std::endl;
  }
  ~Class_A() 
  {
    std::cout << "Class_A Deconstructed:" << saved_string << std::endl;
  }
  std::string saved_string;
};

class Class_B 
{
public:
  Class_B(std::string a_string) 
    : saved_string(a_string)
  {
    std::cout << "Class_B Constructed:" << saved_string << std::endl;
  }
  ~Class_B() 
  {
    std::cout << "Class_B Deconstructed:" << saved_string << std::endl;
  }
  std::string saved_string;
};


int main () 
{
  std::cout << "Welcome to the lifetime test." << std::endl;
  Class_A a_a("A");
  Class_B a_b("B"); //Now I have to have () here too
  std::cout << "Now for the interesting bit." << std::endl;
  Class_A("a"); //Have to have the ()
  Class_B("b");
  std::cout << "Fin." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Which when executed produces:

```
$ ./a.out 
Welcome to the lifetime test.
Class_A Constructed:A
Class_B Constructed:B
Now for the interesting bit.
Class_A Constructed:a
Class_A Deconstructed:a
Class_B Constructed:b
Class_B Deconstructed:b
Fin.
Class_B Deconstructed:B
Class_A Deconstructed:A
```

So I can now see the lifetimes and I am compelled to use `()` or rather `("string")` in the appropriate places.  It is a little odd that `a_a()` is a function declaration inside a function in the First Attempt but `a_a_("A") is a constructor in the second.  I was unaware that it was permitted to declare functions inside the definition of other functions but I suppose it make some sense for a few times when you might have some odd linkage going on in the background.

The lifetime of the unnamed temporary is only as long as the expression it is part of.  Up until the `;`.

### First Attempt

I got as far as:

```
class Class_A 
{
public:
  Class_A() 
  {
    std::cout << "Class_A Constructed" << std::endl;
  }
  ~Class_A() 
  {
    std::cout << "Class_A Deconstructed" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Class_B 
{
public:
  Class_B() 
  {
    std::cout << "Class_B Constructed" << std::endl;
  }
  ~Class_B() 
  {
    std::cout << "Class_B Deconstructed" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main () 
{
  std::cout << "Welcome to the lifetime test." << std::endl;
  Class_A a_a();
  Class_B a_b;
  std::cout << "Now for the interesting bit." << std::endl;
  Class_A(); //Have to have the ()
  Class_B();
  std::cout << "Fin." << std::endl;

  return 0;
```

Which produces:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
$ ./a.out 
Welcome to the lifetime test.
Class_B Constructed
Now for the interesting bit.
Class_A Constructed
Class_A Deconstructed
Class_B Constructed
Class_B Deconstructed
Fin.
Class_B Deconstructed
```

So I only have 1 `Class_A` constructed.  Which is a little confusing as I would have expected `a_a` and `a_b` to have the same lifetimes.  Now what have I done.
(update to follow I am sure)

It does seem to show that the calls to a constructor without a variable name only exist for the line/statement they are in (until the `;`).  This makes some sense when I think about functors, as pointed out by @douglas-o-moen

Comment: `Class_A a_a()` is a function declaration not a variable. That is why you only have one `Class_A` constructed and destructed.

Comment: `a_a` is a function. That is why you're missing one object.

Comment: `int an_int(5)` was the style I was trying to replicate but I guess that `()` and `(void)` might not be exactly the same.  Constructors also have a few rules around their use which might clarify some of the mistaken assumptions I have.

Comment: Following recent standards you can write `Class_A a_a{};` to avoid the function declaration.

Comment: @BoPersson would that not cause it to be a definition instead or does it just look like an inline definition?

Comment: @TafT - The `{}` means initialization, so rules out the possibility of it being a function declaration.

Comment: @BoPersson The {} positioned where it is looks like a function definition instead of a declaration.  I am not sure it does anything to force the use of a Class_A constructor that takes no variables.  It would probably avoid a compiler warning but it would not be doing anything like the intended behaviour.